# JS slideshow with a background color change in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I decided to try to create a slideshow using animation from CSS for Background with a second layer in Javascript using `Jquery`.

The Javascript is functioning correctly, yet the CSS background is not correct. Here is the code for both.
The Javascript code was borrowed from W3Schools' [Automatic Slideshow example](http://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_slideshow.asp).

CSS:

```
body {
  animation-name: change_color; animation-duration: 10s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}  
@keyframes change_color {
  { from (0%) }
  { to (100%) }
}
```

Javascript:

```
var slideIndex = 0;
carousel();

function carousel() {
  var i = 0;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  slideIndex++;
  if (slideIndex > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(carousel, 10000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: It's actually not working

Answer (score 1):

Well, I can only assume what you want due to the lack of HTML, but the problem lies in the CSS:

```
@keyframes change_color{
   {from (0%)}
   {to (100%)}
}
```

A from-to keyframe goes like this (the `from(0%){} to(100%){}` is automatic):

```
@keyframes change_color{
   from {
     background-color: red;
   }
   to {
     background-color: blue;
   }
}
```

The [keyframes documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) is a nice source.

Here's some alternate CSS.

**CSS:**

```
body {
  background-color: black; /* whatever color you want */
  transition: background-color, 2s, ease-in-out, infinite;
}
```

Using [transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp), you can use the JS to change the style to slowly transition to the wanted color, just change the element's `background-color`, you'll have to do `element.style.backgroundColor='red'`.